# How to write bits of data to form a binary file ?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I read a binary file (file can be anything.. like jpg or any kind of binary file or even text file)bit by bit. How to get the same file back with those bits ?

Comment: Umm, just read it again the same way you did the first time.

Comment: *I read a binary file bit by bit* . No you didn´t

Comment: You mean to say "byte by byte", I suppose, and not "bit by bit", also what are you trying to achieve here? What do you mean when you say "How to get the same file back with those bits?"

Comment: You should specify what have you tried so far and what were the results?

Answer (score 1):

Considering how broad your question is, I'm just taking a stab in the dark. Assuming you read a file byte by byte, then converted each byte into a bit string, you could use the following function to reverse this:

```
string readBitString(ifstream &stream)
{
    stringstream input;

    char c;
    while (stream.get(c))
    {
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            input << ((c >> i) & 1);
        }
    }

    return input.str();
}

void writeBitString(ofstream &stream, string input)
{
    stringstream inputStream(input);

    char bits[9];
    char c;

    while(inputStream.get(bits, 9))
    {
        for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(bits[7-i] == '1')
            {
                c |= 1 << i;
            }
            else
            {
                c &= ~(1 << i);
            }
        }

        stream << c;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    ifstream in("test.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream out("test-out.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

    string input = readBitString(in);
    in.close();

    writeBitString(out, input);
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```